# Place two inline divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to bring the tags and categories in a single row but, it doesn't happen whatever I do. Both the divs are inline-block, but they don't come in a single line. 
This is the CSS

```
.categories{float:left; margin-right:3px; margin-bottom: 1px;}
.categories a {
background: #00A1E0;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 2px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 1px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
} 
.categories a:hover{background:  #666; color:#fff;}

.tags{float:left; margin-right:1%;margin-bottom: 4px;}
.tags a {
background:#666666;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding: 1px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
} 
.tags a:hover{color:#FFFFFF;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="categories"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div>
```

Anyways, this is the way it shows up on my browser:-
[image]

But, this is how I want it to look:-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
float: left;
```

add this to both divs and incase the width is exceeding resize it by using % (Percentage) in spite of px

Comment: float left is alreay present in both the divs.

Comment: its a whole wordpress theme on wordpress. can't do it on codepen. am sorry

Comment: you may select the html and do a code pen, just simply directly from the browser. *Firebug*

Comment: maybe there's a problem in the code which comes before the `tags` or `categories`. Any ideas how to debug?? actually, the code works fine on a theme, but not on the one which i am trying to fix right now

Comment: Debug Ideas?

My Way : try-catch blocks
Amateur way: Which I used to do : alert('<code>');  OR echo($foo); die;

Comment: Bro, am really sorry.... It was a css style conflict... there was already a tags class.... its fixed now..

Comment: But, one thing am not able to fix now is the `tags` container doesn't decrease in size when I add `font-size:70%` to `tags a`

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine, here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/o18cfcd0/)** using your code and Bootstrap and custom CSS. May be with Bootstrap it helps to look better.
In the Fiddle frame grab the right side and resize the window.

```
<div class="container col-xs-12 bg-primary">Custom CSS</div>    
<div class="container col-xs-12 block">   
<div class="categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>  
<div class="categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>  
<div class="categories"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>  
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div> 
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div>
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div> 
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div>
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div> 
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div>
<div class="tags"><a href="#"> This Tag</a></div>
</div>
<div class="container col-xs-12 bg-primary">With Bootstrap + custom  CSS</div>    
<div class="container col-xs-12 block">   
<a href="#" class="cat col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 btn btn-info">Categories</a>  
<a href="#" class="cat col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 btn btn-info">Categories</a>  
<a href="#" class="cat col-lg-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 btn btn-info">Categories</a>  
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a>
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a>
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a>
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a>
<a href="#" class="tag col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-5 btn btn-gray">This Tag</a>
</div>
```